# Which design pattern is applied when implementing the methods of Temporal

Tags: design-patterns, java-8, java-time

In the date and time package `java.time`, the methods, especially the `plus(TemporalAmount amount)` and `minus(TemporalAmount amount)`, in the interface `Temporal` are implemented in `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `LocalDateTime` etc. The implementation source code in *OpenJDK* is smart and tricky.

Considering [`LocalTime.plus(TemporalAmount amount)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/LocalTime.java#LocalTime.plus%28java.time.temporal.Temhttp://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/LocalTime.java#LocalTime.plus%28java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount%29poralAmount%29) as an example, the method is implemented by calling the `addTo` method of the parameter `amount`:

```
(LocalTime) amountToAdd.addTo(this)
```

On the other hand, when drilling down to the implementation of `addTo` method in, e.g., [`Duration`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/Duration.java#Duration.addTo%28java.time.temporal.Temporal%29), the overloaded `plus` method of `Temporal` parameter is called:

```
if (seconds != 0) {
      temporal = temporal.plus(seconds, SECONDS);
} if (nanos != 0) {
      temporal = temporal.plus(nanos, NANOS);
}
```

This seems to make use of some design patterns. Could anyone tell **which design pattern is used in the mentioned implementation? or is it a kinda hydrid of several design pattern?**

Answer (score 2):

If any I would say `Strategy` would apply. Because in essence you are saying I will allow you to provide a means of performing a differential calculation, I don't care how it's done, and then you can plug into the additional apparatus we have here (operators). Kind of an FP version of Strategy (which is already pretty FP friendly).

Comment: But usually the *strategy* object is stored as an instance variable other than a parameter of a method, isn't it so?

Comment: In an OOP sense, yes. But in a procedural sense, I'd agree: allowing for the algorithm to be chosen at runtime via (dependency inversion) sounds like the strategy pattern. Although some may argue this is simply polymorphism. Since this answer says "If any..", I'd say it applies (may want to include "some may consider this to be nothing more than polymorphism").